# ConstraintLayout shows bad layout on preview even though on blueprint is ok

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My layout looks likes this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/silver"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/newsListItemView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_picture"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_height="150dp">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnLike"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_oval_vd_wrap"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivImage"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivImage"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hearth_off"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLike"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLike"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="288dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDate"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is preview how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see layout on blueprint (right side) is rendered correctly. On  preview (also on real device), like button (white button with hearth inside) has bad position even though it's outline is shown correctly. How can I fix it? Is it proper behaviour? I'm using ConstraintLatout beta 4. Should I report this to google?

Answer (score 1):

i tried on a sample project and i didn't found the same issue
as i think it's related to

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_height="150dp"
```

`layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` can work if you added `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
but it's not achieving what you want

the better solution is to add
`android:layout_height="150dp"` not `tools:layout_height="150dp"`
and remove `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"`

Comment: Thanks, It was a bug in library. Should be fixed in next beta version. [issue reported to google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231455)

Comment: @LucyFair thank you could you mark it solution for 50% help